# rvalue reference and visual 2013

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct Foo
{
    int *nb;

    Foo() :nb(new int(5)){}

    ~Foo(){ delete nb; }

    Foo(Foo&& f)
    {
            std::cout << "Move\n";
        nb = f.nb;
        f.nb = 0;
    }

}; 

std::vector<Foo> vec;

void func()
{ 
    vec.push_back(Foo()); 
}

int main()
{    
    func();
    std::cout << *(vec[0]).nb << "\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Running:

```
> ./a.out
Move
5
```

Is it normal that under VS2013 `vec.push_back(Foo());` call `Foo(Foo&& f)` ?
I believed that Foo() was a lvalue.

Comment: `Foo()` is **not** an lvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Since the instance that you create by calling Foo() is never assigned to a variable, the compiler will treat it as an r-value.

A short rule of thumb is that any object you create that is not given a name (ie no declaration) will be an r-value.

For a nice explanation of the details I recommend section 6.4.1 in [The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html).

Comment: I simply think visual 2013 don't respect the norm. Foo() is a lvalue so Foo(Foo&&) shouldn't  normally be called

Comment: @Guillaume07: That is wrong, `Foo()` is an rvalue expression, not an lvalue expression

Comment: @David Rodriguez: but under visual I can use the adress operator in front of Foo(), so that lead me to think that Foo() is a lvalue.

Comment: @Guillaume07 In the expression `vec.push_back(Foo())`, `Foo()` does not have an identify; ie you have no way of getting to the value created in the current block. Therefore it is what is called a `prvalue`.

Comment: @Guillaume07: That's a quirk in Visual Studio compiler. It is illegal to take address of `Foo()`. Most likely, the compiler will disable this "feature" if you disable language extensions.

Comment: @Guillaume07: Consider what would happen if you did not pass the object created by `Foo()` to `push_back()`. Since it is a temporary, it would be automatically destroyed at the end of the statement.